# how do i access elements of an array in laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-notification

I am trying to count the number of elements that are equal to a certain value but im struggling to get to the element that i want to compare, when i run:

```
{{dd($numberofnotifications)}}
```

I get the following:

[image]

But the value i need to compare is under 'attributes'

so how do i get to the values under attributes?

When i print out each element of the array i get the following format:

```
{"id":"96a40ebb-a2d1-44d8-9600-e94dd026f152","type":"App\\Notifications\\CommentCreated","notifiable_type":"App\\User","notifiable_id":1,"data":{"comment_id":9,"data":{"name":"John","date":"2020-12-30T08:37:47.000000Z","email":"John@gmail.com","post":2,"body":"test"},"message":"John commented on your post"},"read_at":null,"created_at":"2020-12-30T08:37:47.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-12-30T08:37:47.000000Z"}
```

Comment: Have you added a loop on collection ? It will give you item one by one, then you access using object notation.

Comment: no i have not. would i do that using @foreach?

Comment: Yes, what are you waiting for  then :-)

Comment: you want to compare what about each element to what value?

Comment: i want to compare the name value of each element with the name of the user that is logged in

Comment: i've added the printed version of one element of the 5 so you can see what is looks like. but i am not sure how to get to the 'name'

Comment: Why you didn't use DB where condition? if you want to do that server side you can transform the collection into array  `$numberofnotifications->toArray();` then iterate item by item as in the answers

Comment: toArray(arrayname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the items is an array of DatabaseNotifications. So, you can get each element manually by its index:

```
$numberofnotifications[0]->id;
// or
$numberofnotifications[0]->type
```

or you can use `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($numberofnotifications as $notification) {
    $notification->id;
}
```

Comment: Okay so i have managed to figure it out your way, but now how do i count how many are equal to a value.  this is what ii have managed to use to get to the name value: $notification->data['data']['name'], and this is how i compare the two: $notification->data['data']['name'] == Auth::user()->name. How would i count how many this returns

Comment: Then, use where() and count() befor getting your data: $data = Model::query()->where('your_field', $your_value)->count();

Comment: what like this: transform($notification->data['data']['name'])

Comment: Sorry, I have confused. I've edited my comment above

Comment: like this:   $data = $numberofnotifications->where($notification->data['data']['name'], '==', Auth::user()->name)->count().      This gives me a count of 5 which is the total number of elements which is incorrect. but if i take out the where() and the count it is displaying all the name values that are equal to the current users name which is 4 which is correct

Comment: What is $numberofnotifications here? It is a collection result of model? You should not use ready collection of data. Just use count instead of get(): $numberofnotifications = Notifications::query()->where('username', Auth::user()->name)->count(). If your Notification model have user_id that relates to users table, then try this: $username = Auth::user()->name;
Notification::query()->whereHas('users', function (Builder $query) use ($username) {
 $query->where('username', $username);
})->count();

Comment: numberofnotifications is just a collection of all the unread notifications of the user that is logged in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226601/discussion-between-alisher-nasrullayev-and-es915).

Answer (score 0):

As the result is a collection, you can convert them using

```
$numberofnotifications->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use foreach to iterate through the collection:

```
foreach($numberofnotification as $number)
    {
        $number->name;   //name here is the "name" of the attribute you want to access
    }
```

if you want to store them in an array then:

```
foreach($numberofnotification as $number)
    {
       $attributes[]=$number->name;   //name here is the "name" of the attribute you want to access
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

//consider that $username is the logged in user name

```
$filtered_count = $numberofnotifications->where('name', $username)->count();
```

and if you want the record

```
$filtered = $numberofnotifications->where('name', $username)->all();
```